# Simple slideshow use only css and html

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to develop a simple slideshow using only CSS and HTML? If so, can anyone guide me? Is jquery a must for slideshow development bacause the result of google search almost using along with jquery.

Comment: I suggest searching for "pure css slideshow" to narrow down the results for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [good example](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) of how to achieve just this - written by Smashing Magazine

[Demo](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make simple CSS-HTML slideshow. If you want to use images simply replace h1 tags with img.

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usm10hfy/

Here is the simple code:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
      <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">1</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">2</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">3</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">4</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">5</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1 class="slide-number">6</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<style>  
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 5%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #slideshow {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 510px;
      width: 728px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .slide-wrapper {
      width: 2912px;
      -webkit-animation: slide 10s ease infinite;
    }

    .slide {
      float: left;
      height: 510px;
      width: 728px;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(1) {
      background: #D93B65;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(2) {
      background: #037E8C;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(3) {
      background: #36BF66;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(4) {
      background: #D9D055;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(5) {
      background: #D9D055;
    }

    .slide:nth-child(6) {
      background: #D9D055;
    }

    .slide-number {
      color: #000;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10em;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slide {
      20% {margin-left: 0px;}
      30% {margin-left: -728px;}
      50% {margin-left: -728px;}
      60% {margin-left: -1456px;}
      70% {margin-left: -1456px;}
      80% {margin-left: -2184px;}
      90% {margin-left: -2184px;}
    }
</style>
```

Answer by http://www.joblesspanda.com/

Answer (score -2):

For an html only slideshow use the "http-equiv refresh" meta tag. Simple avoids jscript and functional. One possible  downside, may affect some browsers back button?